# Vue / vuetify focus input after modal is dismissed

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, focus, vuetify.js

On a page I have a Vuetify `v-form`/`v-text-field`. Users can type a query in to this form and press `Enter` to update the page.

Sometimes the query is erroneous and a `v-dialog` modal pops up to explain the error. It's a complex error and can't just be packed in the `rules` attribute of the `v-text-field`.

The problem: when the modal is dismissed, the `v-text-field` is no longer focused and requires a click before it can be used again. This interrupts the user and requires a shift from keyboard to mouse and back.

**What is Vue best practice for re-focusing on the input that triggered the modal?**

I can think of one idea it doesn't feel Vue-ish: put a `ref` on the `v-text-field` and watch the `dialog` data property. If `dialog` becomes `false`, call `this.$refs.input.focus()`. However, this seems like the old-fashioned, imperative (not reactive) way to do it. For example:

```
<template>  
  <v-form v-model='valid' @submit.prevent='submit'>
    <v-text-field
      placeholder="Search..."
      v-model="query"
      :rules="[foo]"
      ref='input'
      autofocus
    ></v-text-field>

    <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog"
      @keydown.esc='dialog = false'
    >
      {{ someErrorMessage }}
    </v-dialog>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

```
// Vue instance
  export default { 

    data: function() {
      return {
        dialog: false,
        query: "",
        valid: false
      }
    },

    ...

    watch: {
      // Focus on query after dismissing an error
      dialog(newState) {
        if (!newState) {
          this.$refs.input.focus();
        }
      }
    },

    methods: {
      foo(value) {
        // ... validate value
      },
      submit(e) {
        if (!this.valid) {
          this.dialog = true;
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: There isn't a "best practice" for this. There's probably just a "ok, that works". An example to play with would be helpful.

Comment: @Bert maybe that's true, but I'm new to Vue and trying to grok it better. Added some example code to play with.

Answer (score 0):

In the dialog element, I'd probably call a method instead of directly changing `dialog` to false. Then in that method, I'd add focus to the textarea with some plain old javascript.