# Vuetify's autofocus works only on first modal open

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to use Vuetify's `v-text-field` `autofocus` however it works only first time. After I close the dialog, it doesn't work anymore.

This is what I am trying to do:

```html
<v-text-field ref="focus" autofocus></v-text-field>
```

While googling I found out that it was a [bug](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1353) that was fixed in some version but they had temporary solution which I also tried:

```js
watch: {
  dialog: (val) ->
    if !val
      debugger
    requestAnimationFrame( =>
      @$refs.focus.focus()
    )
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or it is still a bug? Setting breakpoint I saw that it stops at that point. Can anybody lead me to the right direction?

The only difference I have is that I am using Vuex and the dialog variable is in Vuex store. And the dialog is getter/setter.

```js
dialog:
  get: ->
    return this.$store.state.my_store.isDialogOpen
  set: (value) ->
    this.$store.commit('my_store/MY_MUTATION', value)
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.$nextTick($refs.focus.focus)`? Also perhaps if you have time, you can recreate the issue in codepen.

Comment: @Traxo just tried and the effect is same. Am gonna create example soon.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195763/vue-vuetify-focus-input-after-modal-is-dismissed

Comment: @Traxo [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/xvxv4krnoq) is the sandbox I made

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me was the `v-if="dialog"` because the autofocus prop will only work on initial load which is why it was available only for the first time I opened the dialog.

So the working v-tex-field with autofocus in dialog would look something like this:

```
<v-text-field v-if="dialog" label="Label" autofocus></v-text-field>
```

Comment: This one worked for me on `<v-autocomplete />`, thanks! (**vuetify@1.1.14**)

Comment: We ran into this recently with a slight twist--the component we wanted to use autofocus on was wrapped in another custom component, which was then wrapped with the modal. Something like `<Modal :display="showModal"><Form><v-text-field>` so to get this to work, we added a "display" prop to `<Form>` to then use the `v-if` on `v-text-field`. It looked like this `<Modal :display="showModal"><Form :display="showModal"><v-text-field v-if="display" autofocus>`.

Comment: `Property or method "dialog" is not defined on the instance` of course it's not defined. `autofocus` doesn't work for me anyway.

Comment: @Bersan dialog should be the v-model for <v-dialog>

Comment: Seems in 2021 no need for v-if here, works for me with just autofocus.

Comment: @wondra I do not think what you are describing is caused by the v-if but I might be wrong...

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp turns out you were right and that the position v-if matter, it started to act wierd with `:rules` when it was on parent form.

Answer (score 2):

In your sandbox (but also seems to be the case in your question) you had an error in your code, you removed `return` from the provided workaround:

```
watch: {
  dialog (val) {
    if (!val) return; // you removed `return` here
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      return this.$refs.focus.focus();
    }
  });
```

So actually [it works](https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/RZxqeK)