# How to focus v-textarea programatically in vuetify and typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Seems like impossible now, I tried some crazy stuff like:

```
(this.refs.vtextarea as any).textarea.focus()

((this.refs.vtextarea as Vue).$el as HTMLElement).focus()
```

etc...

Javascript source is hardly readable for me but it's sad to had to do it like this...

Int this some basic stuff, or am I missing something obvious ?

PS: well I see textarea element somewhere there in hierarchy... Maybe I can access by some basic dom child element access way... but this will be like writing worst code of my life.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472947/vuetifys-autofocus-works-only-on-first-modal-open

Answer (score 11):

Vuetify does not always work when focusing input, even with `$nextTick`.

This is how we do it generically for both `input` and `textarea`.  We actually use this code with the `ref` set to our `form` in order to focus the first visible `textarea` or `input`.  However, you can target just the widget that suits your needs.

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
          const theElement = this.$refs.myRef         
          const input = theElement.querySelector('input:not([type=hidden]),textarea:not([type=hidden])')
          if (input) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              input.focus()
            }, 0)
          }
  });
}
```

The delay for `$nextTick` and `setTimeout` is negligible, often required, and will save you time and time again.

You don't *need* to exclude `type=hidden` either, but it can't hurt.

If the `ref` is not an `HTMLElement`, but instead a `VueComponent`, you may need to use `this.$refs.myRef.$el` to get the DOM element.

Answer (score 10):

I got mine to work with this:

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$refs.descriptionDescription.$refs.input.focus()
      })
    })
  },
```

Combination of code from @Thomas and @Steven Spungin

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

you can use the autofocus property

```
<v-text-field
                        autofocus
                        label="Insert Document Number*"
                        single-line
                      ></v-text-field>
```

Comment: This is great for the first load.

Answer (score 3):

```
<template>
   <v-text-area
      ref="myTextArea"
   />
</template>

<script>
   ...
   created () {
      this.$refs["myTextArea"].$refs.textarea.focus()
   }
</script>
```

I did it like this for text-fields. I think it should work the same way.

Comment: for me `this.$refs["myTextArea"].$refs.input.focus();` worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is plain JavaScript, not TypeScript, but this works for me:

```
<v-textarea ref="entry"></v-textarea>


<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.$refs["entry"].focus();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**vuetify 3.x** update:
using Steven Spungin's answer above - you just need to add .$el to the ref to get the internal  reference like so:

```
   <v-text-field
      label=""
      prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
      variant="outlined"
      hint="enter search text"
      v-model="searchTerm"
      @change="SearchSourceStore.search(entityName, searchFields)"
      @keydown.enter="SearchSourceStore.search(entityName, searchFields)"
      :loading="SearchSourceStore.loading"
      focused
      clearable
      ref="searchInput"
    >
    </v-text-field>
```

mounted: function () {
this.$nextTick(function () {
// Code that will run only after the    // entire view has been rendered

```
  const theElement = this.$refs.searchInput.$el;
  const input = theElement.querySelector(
    "input:not([type=hidden]),textarea:not([type=hidden])"
  );
  if (input) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      input.focus();
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

},

Answer (score 1):

work for me

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.$refs.textNote.$refs.input.focus()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working for my *v-text-field* with:

```
setTimeout(() => this.$refs.YOURVTEXTFIELDREF.$refs.input.focus(), 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited in new answer: https://codepen.io/cby016/pen/eQXoBo

Try adding $el after the reference. Like so:

`this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.cancelTestDialog.$el.focus())`

Also make sure 'ref' is defined as an attribute on the component.

Vue refs work by adding a `ref="<customName>"` attribute on a component, which you can select by using this.$refs..

> OLD: You need to wait a tick before the textarea is drawn. You could
>   use tricks like setTimeout or use this Vue function:
>
> `this.$nextTick(() => {
>           this.$refs.<name>.focus()
>         })`
>
> Nexttick basically does the same as setTimeout

Comment: Sadly its not about the next tick here, I call it when it is already rendered and ready.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is this for now:

```
(this.$refs.<name>.$el.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0] as HTMLElement).focus()
```

But as I said in question before I tried it this way, it's as ugly as it can be. But.. works.

Answer (score 0):

Autofocus and tabindex did the trick for me. You can also add the last tabindex to your save button

```
<v-form
      @submit.prevent="saveStuff"
    >
            <v-text-field
              ...
              autofocus
              tabindex="1"
            />
          </v-col>
          <v-text-field                 
              tabindex="2"
            />
          </v-col>
</vform>
```