# how to Transfer between " v-text-fields " with directional keys in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm developing a Vue+Vuetify application. I would like to know if it's possible to  Transfer between " v-text-fields "  with  directional keys to make it easier for the user to work

```
                <v-text-field
                 
                  v-model="pontconu.s.x"
                  label="X"
                  type="number"
                  clearable
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
               <v-col
                cols="12"
                sm="6"
                md="4"
              >
                <v-text-field
                  v-model="pontconu.s.y"
                  label="Y"
                  type="number"
                  clearable
                ></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind both of them with `v-model` to the **same** variable declared inside `data`.

```
<v-text-field v-model="yourVar"
outlined
></v-text-field>
<v-text-field v-model="yourVar"
outlined ></v-text-field>
```

The result should look like this:
[image]

Remember that you cannot bind directly to an object property due like you did in your example due to the way Vue works. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925527/vue-js-bind-object-properties).

Comment: I found what I need here thank you:         
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473731/how-to-focus-v-textarea-programatically-in-vuetify-and-typescript